# Count the number of rows and compare to a given number

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

I want to count rows on my database and use it to check a value on my database

```
$result =mysqli_query($cn,"SELECT * FROM set_ballot");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$room_number = $row['room_number'];
}
$rows= mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($rows==$room_number) {
echo "room full";
}
```

i want the room number to be fetch from database
`if ($rows==5)`
is working.

I guess my if statement is wrong.

I would like to check if the number of rows in my database is the same with the room_number; it should echo "room full". When I use a value in place of `$room_number` it works, but when I use `$room_number` it is not working.

Comment: To make it easier for answerers, or others with similar problems, please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: you will need to tell us what results you are looking to get. if you want to count results, then you can use MySQL's aggregate `COUNT()` function http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx along with any others that could be of use. PHP also has a `count()` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: is the `room_number` column type an integer or text/varchar?

Comment: is an integer @Fred-ii-

Comment: There's something I'm not grasping and can't wrap my head around. I think you may be going about it the wrong way. What is the value of the `room_number` column? I take it that you have a whole bunch of rows with room numbers and you want to count those rows that are taken? If so, you could add an extra column called `taken` for example and set a 0/1 flag, then count those in a `WHERE` clause along with `count()`. I'm thinking outloud here of course, but your question is somewhat unclear for me.

Comment: @fred still not working and is not displaying any error. What im trying to achieve is, i want to count the number of rows in my database and if the number is the same with the number inserted by the admin it should echo room full. for instance there is a table in my database which the admin will insert number of rooms e.g 60 their is a different table for applicant of the room once if the applicant table row is 60 it should echo room full

Comment: hold on, I think I may have something for you. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as I mentioned in comments, you would need to use MySQL's aggregate [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/counting-rows.html) function in order to achieve this, and to count all the rows in your table, then comparing to a given number.

```
$result = mysqli_query($cn,"SELECT COUNT(*) AS number FROM set_ballot");
$num = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$count = $num["number"];
// echo("$count");

if($count == 60){
   echo "Rooms are full. ";
}
else{
   echo "Rooms are not full. ";
}
```

You mention that the number will be coming from user/admin input, so you could also assign a variable to it to replace "60".

```
$admin_number = 60;
```

The query would now read as:

```
$admin_number = 60;

$result = mysqli_query($cn,"SELECT COUNT(*) AS number FROM set_ballot");
$num = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$count = $num["number"];
// echo("$count");

if($count == $admin_number){
   echo "Rooms are full. ";
}
else{
   echo "Rooms are not full. ";
}
```

- I believe that this is what you're looking to do, without knowing what the rest of your database looks like.

---

*Edit:*

Addendum to what I mentioned in comments, and to improve on my answer.

You could add an extra column called "taken" for example and use a 0/1 flagging method, then count those in a `WHERE` clause along with `COUNT()` and using `HAVING/COUNT(column)`.

What I think you may be presently doing is that, you're deleting rows and adding them later on, and this could prove to be inefficient and losing your data, then having to rebuild your rows after.

Here is what I mean:

*Sidenote:* Both `$count_number` and `$admin_number` variables need to match as an integer.

```
$count_number = 60; // count if the number of rows in "taken" has a 1 flag

$admin_number = 60; // the number that the admin enters

$counter = mysqli_query($cn,"SELECT COUNT(*) AS number 
                             FROM set_ballot WHERE taken = 1 
                             HAVING COUNT(taken) = $count_number");

$num = mysqli_fetch_array($counter);
$count = $num["number"];
// echo("$count");

// if($count == 60){

if($count == $admin_number){
   echo " Yep! There are $count_number rooms taken. ";
}
else{
   echo " Nope, some are available. ";
}
```

*Sub-edit*:

Actually, after thinking about it for a bit, there is a slightly better method without having to use 2 variables as I shown you above, by simply using the same variable being `$count_number`:

```
$count_number = 60;

$counter = mysqli_query($cn,"SELECT COUNT(*) AS id 
                             FROM set_ballot WHERE taken = 1 
                             HAVING COUNT(taken) = $count_number");
$num = mysqli_fetch_array($counter);
$count = $num["id"];
// echo("$count");

// if($count == 60){

if($count == $count_number){
   echo " Yep! There are $count_number rooms taken. ";
}
else{
 echo " Nope ";
}
```

---

References:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/counting-rows.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/where-optimizations.html

---

**Footnotes:**

There is probably another way to do this, but this is what I came up with, given my skills in MySQL.

If anyone knows of a better/more efficient method, please leave me a comment.

Comment: @OnahOnallySunday You're welcome. Glad I could help, *cheers*

Comment: @OnahOnallySunday As per what I mentioned in comments yesterday and in regards to using a 0/1 flagging method, I have made an edit to my answer that can be found under ***Edit***. This may prove to be useful for you.

Comment: thanks alot, i really appreciate your effort and your time.

Comment: You're very much welcome @OnahOnallySunday I liked your question.